# Question about proof that $K_{3,3}$ is not a planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I'm reading a proof of the fact that $K_{3,3}$ is not a planar graph, which uses the Euler formula $v-e+f=2$.

This is the proof presented in my lecture notes (which are based on, but not identical to, certain excerpts from Diestel's *Graph Theory*):

Suppose that, to the contrary, $K_{3,3}$ is planar. If $F$ is an arbitrary face (i.e. region) bounded by $K_{3,3}$, **then $F$ is bounded by a cycle**, and since $K_{3,3}$ is bipartite, it must be of even length, so its boundary is of length at least $4$. From there, we have $2e \geq 4f$, where $e$ is the number of edges of $K_{3,3}$, and $f$ the number of faces bounded by $K_{3,3}$, and since $v-e+f=2$, $v=6$, $e=9$, we have $f=5$, and so $9 \geq 10$, which is a contradiction.

Now, the part that's unclear to me is the conculsion that $F$ must be bounded by a cycle. I know that every *bounded* face must be bounded by a cycle, but I don't know that the *unbounded* face is bounded by a cycle. [image]

This image is impossible, I assume, because there is a cycle of odd length here; but this is an example where the boundary of the unbounded face of a planar graph is *not* a cycle.

The part that I failed to emphasize: there is a proposition in Diestel which says that every face of a 2-connected graph is bounded by a cycle - however, there is a note in my lecture notes that the fact that $F$ is bounded by a cycle can be proven without this. Is there an easy answer to this dilemma?

Comment: There's no difference between bounded and unbounded faces, as you see if you embed the graph in the $2$-sphere rather than the plane.

Comment: Right, but even if I embed it into the $2$-sphere, one face can be bounded by a non-cycle, right? I understand that there's a way of higher-level thinking that can render my question pointless, but do you understand the gist of my question - on a lower level of thinking? I'm trying to prove that every face of $K_{3,3}$ is bounded by a cycle, in a very simple way (i.e, without using the fact that every face of a $2$-connected graph is bounded by a cycle, be it embedded in a $2$-sphere or plane. Either way, it's intuitive that all faces but one are bounde by cycles - except for one.

Comment: And that one face, which could hypothetically be bounded by a non-cycle, corresponds to the unbounded face in $\mathbb{R}^2$, or one "arbitrary" (or maybe not arbitrary, but bounded nonetheless) face in $\mathbb{S}^2$.